# Other iOS application version numbers

Tags: ios, version

I have been looking around and I think the answer is 'not possible', however, I need a way for my app to check and display the version numbers of other apps on the same device. I know the names of the other apps (**my apps**) and I don't need to do anything to them, I just need to display the version number. This needs to be done without jailbreaking

Answer (score 0):

You can only share data between apps of the same developer account , so if the other apps are yours also , you can create an app group between them then easily read the version number from the suite defaults , or you can make server-side and read them with an api request

Comment: Thanks. So outside my own apps will never be possible